# Как определить на php успешность выполнения запроса mysql ALTER TABLE

Tags: php, mysql

Как определить на PHP успешность выполнения запроса MySQL `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: Запрос вернет `true` в случае успешного выполнения запроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так (использовал [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php)):

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$query = 'ALTER TABLE t1 RENAME t2;';
if($db->query($query)) {
    echo "It worked"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Из документации по mysqli::$info / mysqli_info() :

> The mysqli_info() function returns a string providing information
>   about the last query executed.
>   …
>      ALTER TABLE ...    Records: 3 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0

По значению после "Records:" можно понять произошли ли какие-то изменения.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php